# Confused about Flink EventTimeTrigger

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

As I know, `EventTimeTrigger` has 4 results, `CONTINUE`, `FIRE_AND_PURGE`, `FIRE`, `PURGE`, when I debug my code, I want to figure out how `EventTimeTrigger` works. So I wrote this code(flink 1.10)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env =   StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        DataStreamSource<Stock> stockDataStreamSource = env.addSource(new StockSource());
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Stock> price = stockDataStreamSource.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Stock>(Time.seconds(1)) {
                    @Override
                    public long extractTimestamp(Stock element) {
                        return element.ts;
                    }
                }
        )
                .keyBy(Stock::getSymbol).timeWindow(Time.seconds(2))
                .min("price");
        price.print("===p");
}
public class Stock {
    public String symbol;
    public long ts;
    public double price;
    public int volume;
...
}

public class StockSource implements SourceFunction<Stock> {

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Stock> ctx) throws Exception {
        try(BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(" " ))) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");

            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] split = line.split(",");
                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(split[1] + " " + split[2], formatter);
                long eventTs = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime).getTime();
                Stock  stock = Stock.of(split[0], eventTs,Double.parseDouble(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]));
                ctx.collect(stock);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {

    }
}
```

and the in put data is

```
US2.AAPL,20200108,093003,297.310000000,100
US2.AAPL,20200108,094001,297.260000000,100
US2.AAPL,20200109,095002,297.270000000,100
```

and the output of is

```
===p> Stock{symbol='US2.AAPL', ts=1578447003000, price=297.31, volume=100}
===p> Stock{symbol='US2.AAPL', ts=1578447601000, price=297.26, volume=100}
===p> Stock{symbol='US2.AAPL', ts=1578534602000, price=297.27, volume=100}
```

When I debug the code, and has a breakpoint in `org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator`, `processElement()` method, `TriggerResult triggerResult = triggerContext.onElement(element);` will return a triggerResult, but the triggerResult is always `CONTINUE`, and I step into, in `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.EventTimeTrigger`, `onElement` method, `ctx.getCurrentWatermark()` always return a negative number, and then return `TriggerResult.CONTINUE`
[image]

In my opinion,when the windows are closed it will return `FIRE_AND_PURGE` rather than `CONTINUE`.
Did I make a mistake in understanding `EventTimeTrigger` or did I make a mistake in writing my program?

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code you've shared looks fine, and will only print results if the windows are, in fact, being triggered. Since the windows are firing, are you sure there's a problem?